# Is my Blowfish algorithm "standard"?

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, endianness, blowfish

I wrote my implementation of a program, in C, in which I can encrypt a text file and vice versa.

The BLOWFISH algorithm is the standard one provided. 
But then my thought is this: if I create a set of 4 chars in a long file, let's say 0x12345678, I can decode it because I know the proper order in which I read the file.

On the other hand, using a pre-made function like `memcpy()`, the content read is ordered like as 0x87654321, not as my previous function do. But the algorithm used is the same.

Is there a "standard" way to read and acquire data from a file, or both of the previous examples are fine? In an online site ([blowfish online](http://blowfish.online-domain-tools.com/)) the version used with `memcpy()` does not comply with that, when using the ECB mode. The version that acquires the data like 0x1234567 is working fine with the site. (Working means making an encrypted file with my program and decrypting it online).

For example, if I code and decode stuff with my program, *that* stuff should be (knowing the key) coded/decoded by other people who don't know my program (as general rule, at least)?

EDIT: the `memcpy()` function translate the lowest index of the array to the right end of the INT number.

This is the code which manipulate data for 64bit block:

```
memcpy(&cl, &file_cache[i], sizeof(unsigned long)); 
memcpy(&cr, &file_cache[i + 4], sizeof(unsigned long));
```

And this is the core part (is working fine, by correctly rearranging the read from the buffer, i.e. looping 8 times for each block) of the same portion which uses bitwise magic instead of memcpy() and comply with the endianess problem:

```
if (i==0){
  cl <<= 24;
  L |= 0xff000000 & cl;
  }
  else if (i==1){
  cl <<= 16;
  L |= 0x00ff0000 & cl;
  }
  else if (i==2){
  cl <<= 8;
  L |= 0x0000ff00 & cl;
  }
  else if (i==3){
  //cl <<= 24;
  L |= 0x000000ff & cl;
  }
  else if (i==4){
  cl <<= 24;
  R |= 0xff000000 & cl;
  }
  else if (i==5){
  cl <<= 16;
  R |= 0x00ff0000 & cl;
  }
  else if (i==6){
  cl <<= 8;
  R |= 0x0000ff00 & cl;
  }
  else if (i==7){
  //cl <<= 8;
  R |= 0x000000ff & cl;
  }
```

Then L and R are sent to be encrypted. This last implementation works if I use other blowfish versions on line, so in principle should be better.

Which implementation is faster/better/lighter/stronger?
If the `memcpy()` is the one adviced, there's a convenient and faster way to reverse/mirroring the content of cl and cr?

Comment: To answer your question you can examine [these blowfish test vectors](https://www.schneier.com/code/vectors.txt) to make sure your implementation matches those results.

Comment: Encryption is defined over a byte stream. Your concern seems to be the difference between little-endian and big-endian values when reading multiple bytes as integers. You have to ensure your code works correctly on byte streams. If you implement the Blowfish algorithm correctly, other people who also implement the Blowfish algorithm correctly should be able to send you data for which you know the key and you should be able decrypt it, and you should be able to send them encrypted data for which they know the key and they should be able to decrypt it. That's why the algorithm is standardized.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the leftmost byte is usually the "first byte send/received" for cryptography; i.e. if you have an array then the lowest index is to the left. If nothing has been specified, then this is the ad-hoc standard.

However, the [Blowfish test vectors](https://www.schneier.com/code/vectors.txt) - as indicated by GregS - explicitly specify this default order, so there is no need to guess:

```
...
All data is shown as a hex string with 012345 loading as
data[0]=0x01;
data[1]=0x23;
data[2]=0x45;
...
```

As long as your code produces the same test vectors then you're OK, keeping in mind that your input / output should comply with the order of the test vectors.

It is highly recommended to make any cryptographic API operate on bytes (or rather, octets), not on other data types *even if those bytes are internally handled as 32 or 64 bit words*. The time required for conversion to/from bytes should be minimal compared to the actual encryption/decryption.

Comment: If I want to use those here: [link](https://www.schneier.com/code/vectors2.txt)
How can I test in an affordable way my application if I my application read/write from/to a file?

Comment: Btw, my code uses the `memcpy()` in which copy from a string 4 chars to fill the width if the int variable of 32bit. The lowest index of string is copied on the RIGHT-end of my number. So the _lowest index is on the right_ and this explains why my code doesn't work with the one implemented on site.

I've used this form:
`memcpy(&cl, &file_cache[i], sizeof(unsigned long));
  memcpy(&cr, &file_cache[i + 4], sizeof(unsigned long));`
to fill the c_left and c_right variables for the blowfish.

Is more o less efficient if I will do bitwise/shift(on cl and cr)  8bit at once?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the file as a sequence of 4-byte words then you would need to account for the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of those words in the memory layout, swapping the bytes as required to ensure the individual bytes are handled in a consistent order.

However, if you read/write your file as a sequence of bytes, and stored directly in sequence in memory (in an unsigned char array for example) then the data in file should have the same layout as in memory. That way you can obtain a consistent encoding/decoding whether you encode directly from/to memory or from/to file.